# Can I mix 22awg and 26awg hookup wire in the same circuit?

Tags: arduino-uno, wires

I'm still fairly new to Arduino projects, and am only just now getting into building circuits where I want to cut and place my own hookup wire instead of using the precut jumper wires. I inherited some supplies from a friend who abandoned the hobby, and about half of the wire he gave me is 22awg and the other half is 26awg. All of it is solid core copper. Is it ok to mix wire gauges like this in the same circuit/project?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you won't ever put more current through it than the 26AWG wire can handle, you'll be safe.

Comment: Thanks. Any tips on where to get reliable info on what 26AWG copper (for example) can handle? In searching just now, I found charts & answers that indicate everything from .3 to 6 amps.

Comment: It depends on how warm you can let the wire get. I wouldn't let it get above 75degC total, so assuming 20degC ambient, that's a 55K rise. You plug that and the wire gauge into a calculator, and it will spit out the maximum allowable current.